# In Magento 2 Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "optgroup: function(){return options }"

Tags: magento2, checkout

In magento 2, how to get a  custom attribute  option value in select field in checkout page

[image]

> app/code/Cm/CustomerAttribute/Model/Plugin/Checkout/LayoutProcessor.php

```
    <?php
namespace Cm\CustomerAttribute\Model\Plugin\Checkout;
class LayoutProcessor
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array  $jsLayout
    ) {

        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['custom_field'] = [
            'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
            'config' => [
                'customScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes',
                'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/select',
                'options' => [],
                'id' => 'custom-field'
            ],
            'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes.custom_field',
            'label' => 'Custom Field',
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'visible' => true,
            'validation' => [],
            'sortOrder' => 250,
            'id' => 'custom-field',
            'options' => [
                    [
                        'value' => '',
                        'label' => 'Please select'
                    ],
                    [
                        'value' => '1',
                        'label' => 'One'
                    ],
                    [
                        'value' => '2',
                        'label' => 'Two'
                    ],
                    [
                        'value' => '3',
                        'label' => 'Three'
                    ]
                ]
        ];


        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

Please some one help me to get a attribute option

Comment: got any solution  ?

Comment: Yes , finally i found a solution wait i will posted as a answer

Comment: i updated the answer @manish

Answer (score 4, accepted):

code:

```
      <?php 
    namespace Cm\CustomerAttribute\Plugin\Checkout\Block\Checkout;

    class LayoutProcessor
    {
        protected $customerSession;
        protected $resultPageFactory;
        public function __construct(\Cm\CustomerAttribute\Helper\Customerattribute $helper,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession)
        {
            $this->helper = $helper;
            $this->customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
            $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        }
        public function afterProcess(
            \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
            $jsLayout
        ) {
            $attributeCollection = $this->helper->getUserDefinedAttribures();

           if ($attributeCollection->getSize() > 0) 
           {
             foreach ($attributeCollection as $attribute)    
             {
            if ($this->helper->isAttribureForCheckoutRegister($attribute->getAttributeCode()))
            {
            $frontEndLabel = $attribute->getStoreLabel($this->helper->getStoreId());

            $customAttributeCode = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
              $customerAttr = NULL;

          if($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            $customerId =$this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
             $customer =$this->customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customerId);
             if($myCustomAttribute = $customer->getCustomAttribute($customAttributeCode)) {
                     $customerAttr = $myCustomAttribute->getValue();
              }     
            }
            else
            {
              $customerAttr =NULL;
            }
            $sortOrder = $attribute->getSortOrder();
            $fieldRequiredClass = ($attribute->getIsRequired()) ? 'true' : '' ;
            if($fieldRequiredClass == '')
            {
                $fieldRequiredClass = false;
            }
            $fieldFrontendClass = ($attribute->getFrontendClass()) ? $attribute->getFrontendClass() : '';
            $fieldInput =$attribute->getFrontendInput();
            $attributeId = $attribute->getAttributeId();
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

            $attributeOptionAll = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Option\Collection::class)
                                        ->setPositionOrder('asc')
                                        ->setAttributeFilter($attributeId)
                                        ->setStoreFilter()
                                        ->load();
            $opt_val = array();
            $allOptions=array();


            foreach ($attributeOptionAll->getData() as $key => $v) 
            {
              // $allid = $v['attribute_id'];
              $opt_val['value'] = $v['option_id'];
              $opt_val['label'] = $v['value'];
              $allOptions[] = $opt_val;
            }



            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
            ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children'][$customAttributeCode] = $this->addNewField($customAttributeCode,$frontEndLabel,$fieldRequiredClass, $fieldFrontendClass, $fieldInput,  $allOptions, $customerAttr, $sortOrder );


            }
          }
        }
        return $jsLayout;
        }

        private function addNewField($customAttributeCode, $frontEndLabel, $fieldRequiredClass,  $fieldFrontendClass, $fieldInput, $allOptions, $customerAttr , $sortOrder )
        {
            if($fieldInput == 'text')
            {
                $fieldInputType = 'input';
                $fieldAbstract =  'abstract';
                $fieldVisible = true;
            }
            elseif ($fieldInput == 'date') {
               $fieldInputType = 'date'; 
               $fieldAbstract =  'date';
              $fieldVisible = true;

            }
            elseif ($fieldInput == 'select') {
               $fieldInputType = 'select'; 
               $fieldAbstract =  'select';
               $fieldVisible = true;

            }
            elseif ($fieldInput == 'multiselect') {
               $fieldInputType = 'input'; 
               $fieldAbstract =  'abstract';
               $fieldVisible = false;
            }
            elseif ($fieldInput == 'boolean') {
               $fieldInputType = 'select'; 
               $fieldAbstract =  'select';
               $fieldVisible = true;
               $allOptions = [
                     ['value' => '0', 'label' => 'No'],
                     ['value' => '1', 'label' => 'Yes']
                   ];
            }
             elseif ($fieldInput == 'textarea') {
               $fieldInputType = 'textarea'; 
               $fieldAbstract =  'textarea';
               $fieldVisible = true;

            }
            $customField = [
                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/'.$fieldAbstract.'',
                'config' => [
                    'customScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes',
                    'customEntry' => null,
                    'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                    'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/'.$fieldInputType.'',

                ],
                'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes' . '.' . $customAttributeCode,
                'label' => $frontEndLabel,
                'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                'validation' => [$fieldFrontendClass => true , 
                    'required-entry' => $fieldRequiredClass],
                'options' =>  $allOptions,
                'filterBy' => null,
                'customEntry' => null,
                'visible' => $fieldVisible,
                'value' => $customerAttr
            ];

             return $customField;
        }

}
```

**Note:**

change `'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',` into  `'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',`

Comment: Thanks Its working :)

Comment: Happy coding :) @Manish

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

The component option of your custom_field must be declare as "Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select" instead of "Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract".

Regards.