# Magento 2 Country and Region/state not showing values on checkout address form randomly

Tags: magento2, checkout, customer, onepage-checkout, shipping-address

I am facing an issue with magento 2.2.11 this happens ramdonly, Country field and region/state field do not load select values on checkout address form

[image]

I've checked that in **`stores->configuration->general->"Country options"`** Default country is set and in State options "State is required" for default country.

As I said this happens ramdonly on pageload mainly for guest users.

Has anyone ever occurred the same issue?

Thank you

Comment: When this error happens, try looking at the console. Checkout process ios almost entirely working with JS / KnockotuJS. Any JS error might break other process, thus prevent the dropdown inputs from being loaded

Comment: Hello Cladiuss , thank you for your reply. Indeed I see an error in  console log: "Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "optgroup: function(){return options }"
Message: caption is not defined"  same as in this thread: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/280897/in-magento-2-uncaught-referenceerror-unable-to-process-binding-optgroup-funct?